# Should I downvote an answer when it is wrong while reviewing?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, downvotes, downvote-reason

I suppose the key point of review is to determine if a question/answer is a real question/answer. I should downvote, if an answer is not a real answer (the user asks another question maybe).

When reviewing, should I only check if the answer is a real answer and nicely formatted? Or should I also check if the answer is wrong for the question asked? Or contain obvious errors? If it is, should I downvote them too?

Comment: _"Or should I also check if the answer is wrong to the question?"_ If you have the expertise to decide, downvote yes.

Comment: The purpose of voting is to determine the usefulness of content. The purpose of the review queue is to get content in front of people that may need action taken. Going the extra mile is always appreciated.

Comment: Also, you should know that an answer -1 will still cost you a rep point in the review queues. If you're not okay with that, just skip and the answer will appear for someone else (and if it needs a -1, they'll probably be more than happy to provide one). Just don't NAN it!

Comment: To expand on @PeterG's comment. If you downvote you will indeed receive a -1. If that answer is removed at any point you'll get that rep back. As you gain more and more rep you'll become less and less concerned about a -1. The fact you're asking about this shows you have some concern over the content, which is good. Don't be afraid to downvote if the answer is terrible.

Comment: "I should downvote, if an answer is not a real answer (the user asks another question maybe)." In that case downvoting is optional: the most important part is flagging it as Not An Answer (NAA). When I do raise such a flag I normally don't bother to downvote, simply because it will be deleted in any case. But you can do it, it's even free, since as Bugs said you'll get your rep back as soon as it is deleted.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It doesn't matter how you come upon an answer.
No matter if it's in the review queue or not (or, in *which* review queue), if you're looking at a post and you see it needs downvoting or flagging or editing, just do so.